# How Can I increase Kafka producer throughput?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, throughput

I am building an Apache kafka producer that is consumed by flink Kafka consumer. I need to generate 1 million up to 10 million message per second. However I am getting very small number of records per second now (up to 2000 per second per partition). I have a cluster with 3 brokers and 30 gb memory in each. The topic has also 10 partitions. Any recommendations please?

Here is my producer code

```
public class TempDataGenerator implements Runnable {
private String topic = "try";
private String bootStrap_Servers = "kafka-node-01:9092,kafka-node-02:9092,kafka-node-03:9092";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    executor.execute(new TempDataGenerator());

}
public TempDataGenerator() {
}

private Producer<String, String> createProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootStrap_Servers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG,"0");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG,"5000000000");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG,"100000");

    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}
public void run() {

    final Producer<String, String> producer = createProducer();
    Socket soc = null;
    try {
        boolean active = true;
        int  generatedCount = 0,tempUserID=1;//the minimum tuple that any thread can generate
        while (active) {
            generatedCount = 0;

                /**
                 * generate per second
                 */
                for (long stop = Instant.now().getMillis()+1000; stop > Instant.now().getMillis(); ) { //generate tps

                    String msg = "{ID:" + generatedCount + ", msg: "+Instant.now().getMillis()+"}";
                    final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, msg);
                    RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
                    producer.flush();
                    generatedCount++;

                }

        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: You're trying to produce that many messages on only a single machine? Don't call `.get()` and flush for every message, and then it'll be faster

Comment: create multiple producers, that is only the way

Comment: Thank you very much @cricket_007.
you mean by multiple threads that produce to the same topic?

Comment: yes multiple producer threads @ahmadi

Comment: Multiple threads. Multiple running instances. Multiple producers on completely different machines... All the above. Just don't use blocking calls for getting the result or flushing for every message

Comment: It's advisable not only to use multiple producers, but also to maintain stickiness between producer and topic partition. So use 10 producers (as the amount of partitions) and when you send a message, choose the producer according to the target partition. This way you will get the maximum out of batches. Otherwise, you will see that batches are smaller than expected

Comment: Thank you very much @cricket_007 and Lior Chaga I made producer to produce for one second and made message as a counter that resets to zero every second. Then sleep for a while. Meanwhile, I created a console consumer and printed the messages (counter) . After making your recommendations cricket_007 it hits average of 250,000 record per second for a single thread which is almost satisfying and obviously will increase by using multi producers and partitions. Now the problem shifted to the flink consumer I edited the question and add the context there. Any suggestions please

Comment: Please create a separate post for Flink questions since that's a separate issue

Comment: I apologize for that. I will remove the additional part now.